# theme content type with image from within paragraph

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I'm trying to create a twig layout for a Person content type that is be used within Paragraphs.
My twig file is paragraph--person-profile--default.html.twig.

I can get the Person name with `{{ content.field_person[0]['#node'].title.0.value }}`

I cannot get the image. I've tried the following:

`{{ content.field_person[0]['#node'].field_image.0.value }}`

and `{{ content.field_person[0]['#node'].field_image.0 }}`

The following error is reported.

> Exception: Object of type Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter()

The end game is to have a taxonomy term and a person content type within a paragraph type. The taxonomy term will be used to to style the person.
The same person may be styled differently on different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the url from an image field you have to go one level deeper, `.entity` gets the file entity where the URI of the image is stored:

```
{{ file_url(content.field_person[0]['#node'].field_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}
```

But digging through multiple levels of nested entities is not good practice, because this produces code hard to debug and maintain. You should look for a  better place to theme the image, for example `node--person.html.twig`, where you can print the image field, formatted how it is configured in UI:

```
{{ content.field_image }}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had gotten lost in the trees and couldn't see the forest.
I ended up being about to get the styling field I wanted from the paragraph. I then had to go to the person template to do the other styling.


`<div class="person_profile" class="{{ content.field_display_type[0]['#title'] }}">
  {{ content.field_person.0 }}
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi bart please refer the below link, it will be helpfull for getting the full URL of the image.

After that you can use Image Tag for rendering the image

[Rendering Image Field](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2016-12-21/render-image-field-as-background-image-in-twig-not)